# Django Queryset Batches

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, django, python-3.x

I have a Django app that runs on SQL Server. SQL Server allows a maximum of 2,100 parameters in a user-defined function. I have a Django view with a queryset that should return 10,000 results when called:

```
def result_list(request):
    results = MyModel.objects.filter(~(Q(importantField='') | Q(importantField='Some Text'))).select_related('field','field2','field3','field4').prefetch_related('anotherField')
    return render(request, 'results/result_list.html', {'results':results})
```

I have a template that attempts to return those 10,000 results

```
{% for result in results %}
    <!-- put results into an HTML table -->
{% endfor %}
```

Error:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: https://server/results/result_list

Django Version: 1.11.3
Python Version: 3.6.3

Traceback:

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py" in execute
  545.             return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "D:\Websites\project\app\views.py" in result_list
  476.     return render(request, 'results/result_list.html', {'results':results})

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
  30.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  68.     return template.render(context, request)

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  207.                     return self._render(context)

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  107.     return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  177.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  107.     return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  72.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  216.                 return template.render(context)

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  209.                 return self._render(context)

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  107.     return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  173.             len_values = len(values)

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in __len__
  232.         self._fetch_all()

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _fetch_all
  1120.             self._prefetch_related_objects()

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _prefetch_related_objects
  675.         prefetch_related_objects(self._result_cache, *self._prefetch_related_lookups)

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in prefetch_related_objects
  1469.                 obj_list, additional_lookups = prefetch_one_level(obj_list, prefetcher, lookup, level)

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in prefetch_one_level
  1599.     all_related_objects = list(rel_qs)

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in __iter__
  250.         self._fetch_all()

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _fetch_all
  1118.             self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in __iter__
  53.         results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch)

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  886.             raise original_exception

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  876.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  80.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __exit__
  94.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py" in reraise
  685.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py" in execute
  545.             return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: Error at /djangoProject/results/result_list
Exception Value: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

How do I change my view and/or template to batch the ORM query to get around the limit on parameters?

I know the `iterator` exists, but I believe that queries the database individually for each record, rather than batching queries for every 1,000 or 2,000 records.

I can slice the queryset by adding `[:1000]` to the end, but I'm not sure how to incorporate that into a loop that unions all of the slices together.

Comment: Is the limit on number of records (rows) or parameters passed to the query?
Your query in the question contains only very limeted (2) number of parameters. And about ther iterator, iterator skips caching in django ORM, but it doesn't mean that it hits db for each record