# Django Convert Normal Queryset to Iterator

Tags: python, sql-server, django, python-3.x

I have a Django view:

```
def object_search_list(request):
    if request.user.get_username() in ['username']:
        objects = MyModel.objects.filter(some_field='filter value').select_related('another_field').prefetch_related('a_third_field')
    else:
        objects = MyModel.objects.filter(some_field='a different filter value').select_related('another_field').prefetch_related('a_third_field')
    return render(request, 'objects/object_list.html', {'objects':objects})
```

My backend, SQL Server, has a limitation of 2100 paramaters in a query. Therefore, the `prefetch_related` is causing an error because it is putting more than 2100 parameters into the `IN` statement of the SQL Server query.

How would I use `iterator()` (if possible) to replace `prefetch_related`?

I understand that it will look something like this:

```
objects = MyModel.objects.filter(some_field='filter value').select_related('another_field').iterator()
for o in objects:
    #do something
```

This view is rendered with the following template:

```
{% for object in objects %}
<td>{{ object.id }}</td>
<td>{{ object.field }}</td>
<td>
    {% for a_third_field in object.third_fields.all %}
      {{ a_third_field }}{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</td>
<td>{{ object.another_field }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

But I'm not sure how to directly convert rendering a queryset to a template into rendering an iterated queryset to a template. How would I make that conversion?

Comment: what do you want to get out of the `iterator()` though? A sample of the output you want?

Comment: I want the same as I get out of the straight queryset. The queryset is being fed into an HTML table

Comment: @Dora I updated the question with the template

Comment: not sure if I am right now I don't really see much error there if I didn't get your idea wrong.  You just want to pass `queryset` into the template engine of django which has nested fields that also contains relationship to other models.  What do you get from the output of `{{ a_third_field }}` if there is nothing, try something like `third_fields_set.all` depending on how you setup your model

Comment: I forgot if it's `set` or `sets`

Comment: It works when I filter the the results down to a small number. When I leave the filter where it is (~8000 results), it hangs with iterator and won't load the page. I thought iterator would speed it up slightly. Is there a way to use iterator with StreamedHTTPResponse and still render to a template?

Comment: That is weird, why not trying the simplist queryset first such as `objects = MyModel.objects.filter(some_field='filter value')` and see if you get all the results back.  Just a thought

Comment: I do - the problem comes because of the problem I mentioned where my backend (SQL Server) limits params to 2100, so the prefetch_related breaks when I have 8000 results. If I remove prefetch_related, Django is now making 8000+ database queries, and it hangs. I thought iterator might allow me to chunk the results.

Comment: Alright, got what you mean but if you want to chunk results, doesn't django's `paginator` should do it?

Comment: that would create separate pages, right? my pages and everything are already managed with JS DataTables. I'm just trying to figure out how to circumvent the 2100 limit on parameters. My related question may shed some more light: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53399114/django-queryset-batches

Comment: getting a better understanding what is going on now.  But just not sure why the page load is stuck when you have 8000 queries.  Give `yeild` a try and see if that would help a bit if not then I am out of opinions sorry about this :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185504/discussion-between-cameron-taylor-and-dora).